# What is the best way to create a login on iOS to MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, ios, ipad, authentication

I have a website which I can log into made in PHP. Now I'm trying to make the same login page on the iPad.

I have two textfields and a login button and it's set up like this when I tap login:

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    NSString *username = usernameTextfield.text; 
    NSString *password = passwordTextfield.text;

    NSString *anURL;

    anURL = @"http://www.mydomain.com/login.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:anURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", username, password];
    [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *dataStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", responseData];

    [statusLabel setText:dataStr]; // This is just to see what data I get back…
}
```

And this is my PHP file "login.php":

```
<?php

include("config.php"); //<- db connection

session_start();

$message = "";

$username = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])); 
$password = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

$submit = $_POST["submit_login"];

$md5_password = md5($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usr_table WHERE usr_name = '$username' and md5_password = '$md5_password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 1) {
        $user_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $user_fetch['usr_id'];
        $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $user_fetch['usr_name'];

        $message = "Login OK";

    } else {
        $message = "Login NOT OK";
    }

echo $message;

?>
```

I just seem to get the data back in HEX format? How can I translate that and treat it in a good way? Am I logged in at this point or is it a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance,
Viktor Gidlöf

Comment: You're sending passwords over http, you really should be using https for authentication of this type.

Answer (score 0):

After you receive the response from your server you should convert it from NSData to NSString:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *responseStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
NSLog(@"%@", responseStr);
```

You might also consider making an asynchronous request instead, so that you do not block the main thread in your app while waiting for the response.